# How do I Cut a range from one worksheet to Paste to a second and make sure future lines go to the next blank row?

Tags: excel, vba, paste, cut, commandbutton

Two questions:

1) I have a spreadsheet (TC) that has data on one page that will be updated daily. There are 28 columns. Essentially I am looking to have the line (row) data cut and paste into a second spreadsheet (Archive) when Col. 28 has a value entered in it. I have the base coding but for some reason it causes Excel to be non-responsive.

I think it might be because the coding goes cell by cell rather than row by row. Can anyone point me in the right direction? (Again, keep in mind, this is a snippet of the coding - I have each Cut and Paste up to Column 28.)

2) The second part of my question is: Will what I have written make sure that when the Command Button is pressed next time, the data will cut and paste to the next blank line. Thank you!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
a = Worksheets("TC").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
'Dim rng As Range
'Set rng = Worksheets("Archived").Range("A1")
b = 1

For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets(“TC”).Cells(i, 28).Value <> "" Then
'Change # to be the number column of Pt Name
         Worksheets(“TC”).Cells(i, 1).Cut
'Change ,# to be the number column of where you want it pasted.
         Worksheets(“TC”).Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Archive”).Cells(b + 1, 1)
'Change ,# to be the number column of SOC
        Worksheets(“TC”).Cells(i, 2).Cut
'Change ,# to be the number column of where you want it pasted.
        Worksheets(“TC”).Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Archive”).Cells(b + 1, 2)

        b = b + 1
    End If
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(“TC”).Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim i as long, b As Long, shtTC as worksheet, shtArch as worksheet

    Set shtTC = Worksheets("TC")
    Set shtArch  = Worksheets("Archive")

    'find the first empty row 
    b = shtArch.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'pick a column which will always be populated              

    For i = 2 To shtTC.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row      
        If shtTC.Cells(i, 28).Value <> "" Then
            'cut the row
            shtTc.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 28).Cut shtArch.Cells(b, 1)
            b = b + 1
        End If
    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    shtTC.Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Ohkay this is nearly perfect.... It executed in about 20 seconds for 474 rows of data (130 that needed to be cut and paste). However, I tried to run it a second time with new lines that have Col. 28 filled and it pasted them to row 79 on the Archive tab. I tried multiple times and it kept returning to Row 79. Any thoughts?

Comment: There's something in B78 on the Archive sheet?

Comment: Then by design it will go to row 79 if that's th first row with no content in ColB (starting from the bottom of the sheet).  To find the start row you need to use a column which will have content for every copied row.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to create the kind of copy results you're looking for. Notice that, unless you specifically want to copy/paste all of the formatting with the data, you don't need to use copy/paste. You can perform the copy by assigning the values of the ranges.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    CopyData ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TC"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Archived")
End Sub

Public Sub CopyData(ByRef source As Worksheet, _
                    ByRef dest As Worksheet, _
                    Optional ByVal deleteSource As Boolean = False)
    '--- calculate and create the source data range
    Const TOTAL_COLUMNS As Long = 1
    Dim srcRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With source
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set srcRange = .Range("A1").Resize(lastRow, TOTAL_COLUMNS)
    End With

    '--- determine where the data should go
    Dim destRange As Range
    With dest
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If lastRow > 1 Then lastRow = lastRow + 1
        Set destRange = .Cells(lastRow, 1)
        Set destRange = destRange.Resize(srcRange.Rows.Count, TOTAL_COLUMNS)
    End With

    '--- now copy the data
    destRange.Value = srcRange.Value

    '--- optionally delete the source data
    If deleteSource Then
        srcRange.Clear
    End If
End Sub
```